# data truncation with Column(UnicodeText) in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I have a model like this

```
class mymodel(Base):
    """
    Unprocessed DataSource model
    """
    __tablename__ = 'mymodel_data'
    mod_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    mod_name = Column(Unicode(150))
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.user_id'))
    all_data = Column(UnicodeText)
```

The `all_data` is a long json text and the size of it can be very very very long.

Sometimes the data gets truncated and the error MSG I get is

```
Warning: Data truncated for column 'all_data' at row 1
```

I need to make sure that the truncation does not happen or I need a workaround. Is there a way? I tried reading [this article](http://www.mydigitallife.info/mysql-error-1170-42000-blobtext-column-used-in-key-specification-without-a-key-length/) but I could not figure out what to do.

I am using mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess I figured it out. I can specify a length for the unicodeText argument. Sorry for the noob question

Answer (score 3):

I guess that on MySQL, the TEXT type is used by default. It has the limit of 64K characters. SQLAlchemy will choose a different type to match the given length argument. As MEDIUMTEXT has an arbitrary limit at 16M, and LONGTEXT (max 4G characters) requires just 1 byte more, you could always use the LONGTEXT for these columns (or use `UnicodeText(length=2**31)`).